# JA018 Oozie Shell Spark Submit Error

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I am trying to run a Spark jar through Spark Submit in the Shell Node of an Oozie workflow. I am getting intermittent JA018 errors. It does the oozie launcher map reduce task, says it succeeds, but  never runs the Spark jar. I can't find anything in any of the yarn or Oozie logs. Am I missing something obvious here?

workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="example-workflow">
 <start to="check-path" />
  <decision name="check-path">
    <switch>
      <case to="run-spark-job">
        ${fs:dirSize(hdfsPath) gt 0}
      </case>
      <default to="end" />
    </switch>
  </decision>
  <action name="run-spark-job">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
          <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
          <configuration>
              <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>${queueName}</value>
              </property>
          </configuration>
          <exec>run-spark-job.sh</exec>
          <argument>${hdfsPath}</argument>
          <env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=${userToRunAs}</env-var>
          <file>${workflowPath}/run-spark-job.sh#run-spark-job.sh</file>
          <capture-output/>
    </shell>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
  </action>
  <kill name="fail">
      <message>Run spark job action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
  </kill>
  <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://{{ namenode_ip}}:8020
jobTracker={{ jobtracker_ip }}:8032
hiveIp={{ hive_ip }}
queueName=default
workflowsRoot=workflows
nameNodeIP={{ namenode_ip }}

userToRunAs=oozie
workflowPath=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${workflowsRoot}/example-workflow
oozie.coord.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${workflowsRoot}/example-workflow
workflowAppPath=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${workflowsRoot}/example-workflow
start={{ start }}
end={{ end }}
user.name=oozie

oozie.use.system.libpath=true
```

coordinator.xml

```
<coordinator-app name="example-coordinator" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" start="${start}" end="${end}" timezone="UTC"
                 xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2">
        <action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>${workflowAppPath}</app-path>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>jobTracker</name>
                    <value>${jobTracker}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>nameNode</name>
                    <value>${nameNode}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>queueName</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>hdfsPath</name>
                    <value>/user/hive/warehouse/test</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </workflow>
    </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code from your workflow.

Comment: Post has been updated with code!